# ¿Cómo puedo transformar un caracter a un número real en R, sin que lo redondeé?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando transformar unas coordenadas que están como tipo caracter a tipo numérico, pero **quiero que mantenga los tres decimales que tiene originalmente.**
He intentado con `as.numeric`, he intentado con `as.double` también, he colocado `options(scipen = 999)`. Pero siempre me redondea a un número real con un decimal.

Comment: `as.numeric` debería convertir a numérico sin pérdida de decimales. Probablemente el problema se encuentre en los datos de entrada, ¿podrías por favor compartir un ejemplo de tus datos?

Comment: $ coordinates:List of 366
  ..$ : chr  "725815.245" "4370727.58" "726055.172" "4370321.337" ...
  ..$ : chr  "722890.269" "4372110.883" "722338.829" "4372047.226"
  ..$ : chr  "725797.497" "4373243.018" "725884.35" "4373375.256"
  ..$ : chr  "725140.37" "4371855.492" "724836.286" "4371370.72"
  ..$ : chr  "724837.047" "4371333.012" "725097.83" "4370890.37"
  ..$ : chr  "728800.385" "4370244.48" "729263.351" "4370414.03"
  ..$ : chr  "728808.725" "4370228.25" "729271.691" "4370397.8"

Comment: Este es el ejemplo. Al final lo que hice fue utilizar options(digits=11) y convertirlo con la función as.double y así me funcionó. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Alejandra, una cosa es el dato y otra es la representación del mismo, `as.numeric()` respeta los decimales siempre, el tema es que por consola se redondean al mostrarlos. `options(digits = 10)` simplemente modifica justamente la forma en que los números se muestran

Answer (score 1):

```
> a<-"140000.768"
> b<-as.numeric(a)
> b
[1] 140000.8
> options(digits = 10)
> b<-as.numeric(a)
> b
[1] 140000.768
```

Comment: Tu respuesta estaría mucho más completa si le dieras una breve explicaras a OP de lo que hace tu código, sé que a veces el código parece muy obvio, pero ayudarás a muchos más usuarios que apenas comienzan y tienen problemas similares. Por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos ;)